# PDE interpretation of some properties of the solution to Fokker–Planck equations

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider

$$X_t=X_0 + \int_0^t b(s)ds+ \int_0^t \sigma(s)dW_s,\quad \forall t\ge 0,$$

where $X_0\ge 0$ is a random variable of density $\rho$, $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is an independent Brownian motion and $b,\sigma$ are measurable function "as nice as possible". Set $\tau:=\inf\{t\ge 0: X_t\le 0\}$ and $Y_t:=X_{t\wedge \tau}$ for $t\ge 0$. Denote by $p(t,\cdot)$ be the density of $Y_t$ restricted on $(0,\infty)$, i.e.

$$\mathbb E[f(Y_t){\bf 1}_{\{Y_t>0\}}] = \int_0^{\infty}f(x)p(t,x)dx,\quad \mbox{for all continuous and bounded function } f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R.$$

It is known that $p$ satisfies the Fokker–Planck equation as below :

\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_t p &=& \frac{\sigma(t)^2}{2}\partial^2_{xx} p - b(t)\partial_x p,\quad \forall t>0, x>0 \\
p(0,x) &=& \rho(x),\quad \forall x\ge 0 \\
p(t,0) &=& 0,\quad \forall t>0. 
\end{eqnarray}

From the probabilistic point of view, it is straightforward to see $p\ge 0$ and the function

$$m(t):=\int_0^{\infty}p(t,x)dx \in [0,1]$$

is non-increasing. From the PDE point of view, why the above Fokker–Planck equation together with the initial and boundary conditions implies $p\ge 0$ and $m$ is non-increasing?

Any answer, comments or references are appreciated.

PS : When $b\equiv 0$ and $\sigma\equiv 1$, one has in view of the reflection principle,

$$p(t,x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2t}\right)-\exp\left(-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2t}\right)\right)\rho(y)dy$$

which clearly satisfies the desired properties. For general $b,\sigma$, do we still have the closed-form expression of $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating $m(t)$ and using the equation leads to
$$
m'(t):=\int_0^{\infty}\left(
\frac{\sigma^2(t)}{2}\partial^2_{xx} p(x,t) - b(t)\partial_x p(x,t)\right)\,dx=
-\frac{\sigma(t)^2}{2}\partial_{x} p(0,t)<0.
$$
The last inequality follows from the Zaremba-Giraud theorem for the sign of the solution's normal derivative at the boundary. See, for example, Nazarov A.I., [*A Centennial of the Zaremba–Hopf–Oleinik Lemma*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0164).

For $b\equiv0$
$$
p(t,x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \int_0^t{\sigma^2(\tau)}\,d\tau}}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2\int_0^t{\sigma^2(\tau)}\,d\tau}\right)-\exp\left(-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2\int_0^t{\sigma^2(\tau)}\,d\tau}\right)\right)\rho(y)dy.
$$
For the general case the Green's function of the first BVP cannot be expressed via elementary functions.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew for the answer. I will accept your solution as soon as I read the paper that you suggested. For the case where $b>0$ is constant, can we expect some "nice" expression for $p$? Here "good" does not mean as explicit as your formula above, but as explicit as possible

Comment: Happy New Year!

Comment: Further, why the positivity of $p$ is ensured by the PDE?

Comment: @GJC20 Positivity follows from $\rho\ge0$, $\rho>0$ somewhere and  the maximum principle. Or, in this case, from the formula for $p$ in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I mean for the general case where $b,\sigma$ that are not constant. Could you please provide the reference of the maximum principle that can be applied here? Also, for the case where $b$ is constant, can we have some "nice" expression for $p$?

Comment: Idk  a nice expression. For the maximum principle in unbounded domains see A. M. Ilyin, A. S. Kalashnikov, and O. A. Oleynik "Linear second-order partial differential equations of the parabolic type".

Comment: Thanks again for the explaination. Do you mean this paper http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/Diff.Equations/Ilyin,Kalashnikov,Oleynik,_Linear_2nd-Order_PDE_of_the_Parabolic_Type,JMS_v108_435.pdf ?

Comment: $~ $ Yes. $~~~      $